# Checking a variable condition in Flask html page

Tags: flask, jinja2

Am having a Flask app which receives json data.This is the json format defined in views.py.

```
Values = [
    {
        'Count':0,
        'RPM':0,
        'ECT':0
    },
    {
        'Count':1,
        'RPM':1,
        'ECT':1
    }
]
```

Each updates json data is passed to html also as argument

```
@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return render_template("members.html",VALS=Values)
```

Inside the html page the json data is treated like this

```
{% for VAL in VALS %}            
    {% if (VAL['ECT'] > 251) %}
        <h1>  -> RPM:,ECT:{{VAL.ECT}} <button type="button" class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">High</button> </h1>
    {% else %}
        <p> {{VAL.Count}} -> RPM:{{VAL.RPM}},ECT:{{VAL.ECT}} <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Normal</button> </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am facing problems with checking condition in if.The condition

```
{% if (VAL['ECT'] > 251) %}
```

is not working. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer

```
{% if (VAL.get('ECT')|int > 251) %}
```

This one will work.Need to convert that to int :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parentheses in Jinja2 syntax.

```
{% if VAL.get('ECT') > 251 %} 
<!-- do stuff -->
{% endif %}
```

Or even `{% if VAL.ECT > 251 %}`.

That format should be sufficient, if you pass a dict into the template from your view. However, if you are passing in JSON, everything is flattened to a string, so you specifically need to filter the value to an int:

```
{% if VAL.ECT|int > 251 %}<!-- do stuff -->{% endif %}
```

Comment: i tried both of your solution but its not working if we use VAL.ECT will it be a string value so does comparing with int value works?

Comment: Ah of course - if you pass the values in as a Python dict to the template, it will work, but JSON is flattened to a string. You need the filter as you showed in your answer.